# Rule of reordering member declaration in class

Tags: c++, class

I'm reading the c++14 N3797 and I've encountered with 3.3.7/1:

> If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid
>   program under (1) and (2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is
>   required.

There are (1) and (2):

> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only
>   of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration,
>   but also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   exception-specifications, and brace-or-equal-initializers of
>   non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).
>
> 2) A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in
>   its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

That is if we write the following:

```
class A
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

then the program is ill-formed. Reorering member declaration yields an alternate valid program:

```
class A
{
    int b;
    int a;
}
```

Might I don't understand this rule correctly?

Comment: Surely this doesn't create an *Alternate Valid Program*. It may look different but it will compile and execute the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "alternate valid program" is referring to a situation in which each ordering of the elements in the class yields a valid interpretation of the program, but the meaning **changes** depending on the ordering.

In your case, changing the order of `a` and `b` is allowed, *but* since their relative order can't affect the meaning of the program, the behavior is defined.

For this to happen, you must use a name in the class that has already been defined with some other meaning outside the class. For example:

```
typedef void *T;

struct whatever {
    T a;
    typedef long T;
};
```

Here, the relative order of the declaration of `a` and the typedef of `T` affects the meaning of the code. As it's written right now, `a` has type `void *`, because the global `typedef void *T;` is in scope when the `T a;` is parsed.

If, however, we rearranged the two so as:

```
typedef void *T;

struct whatever {
    typedef long T;
    T a;
};
```

...the `T a;` is equivalent to `long a;`. The meaning of the program is different due to the relative ordering of the two declarations, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Can you give an example of when its order does affect the meaning of the program?

Comment: Seems I'm beginning to understand. In that case it is principal that the behavior before and after reordering will be potentially different. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. I've added an example.

Comment: Would code such as `if (&whatever::a < &whatever::b)` be considered affected or would that just get fixed and give the intended result anyway?

Comment: @chris: I suppose you could interpret that as falling within the quote above, but I don't think it's intended to be covered. The real intent is things like I've shown above where the basic meaning of the program, such as the type to which `T` refers, being changed when you change the order of declarations. If you included addresses of members (potentially) changing when you changed order, then it would say essentially every struct/class with more than one non-static data member had UB, which I'm pretty sure wasn't intended.

Comment: @chris This was removed by [CWG1875](https://wg21.link/1875). It seems like the intended point was only that names should refer to the same declarations, but yes I think the rule did unintentionally make every class with more than one member UB because of `offsetof` or `sizeof` padding.